# Creating an XML string from php string

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Looking to parse some XML data that is saved in a DB. In the DB its saved in raw XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RESPONSE>
    <SUCCESS>true</SUCCESS>
    <ERRORMESSAGE>
    </ERRORMESSAGE>
    <DATA>
    </DATA>
 </RESPONSE>
```

I want to be able to parse this data, and have found people normally using:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML RAW XML XML;
```

But how can I use a php string in there?

So e.g.

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML $stringfromDB XML;
```

Of course that does not work, but how can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: Please use the search before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML should do the trick for you. Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp) link, along with [php manual basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

```
$xmlData = /* query xml-data from DB as string */;
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlData);
var_dump($xmlObj);
```

the `<<<XML ...some code... XML;` is just an alternative notation for declaring (multiline) strings, you don't have to do that, as long as you can obtain full XML document from DB as in your first snippet.